# Number always missing decimals after calculation

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is summarized wrong and etc.. This is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow, so if I'm making any mistakes, let me know.

**Problem:**
In line 20, code embedded below, I'm performing a calculation, more  specifically this calculation: 11 * 50 / 100, which if I'm not mistaken should give a result of 5.5. But my console gives me a result of 5. Maybe it's because it's late, but I personally can't see a thing wrong in that line.
Or let me know if I'm using `cout` wrong.

**Explanation of program:**
You receive an input of five ages, a ticket cost 10, which results in 50. But you may substract the youngest persons age as percent from the final price.

Kind regards Olle!

```
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int ages[5] = {11,18,19,30,34};
    int ticketPrice = 10;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cin >> ages[i];
    }*/
    int agesSize = *(&ages + 1) - ages;
    int finalPriceWithoutDiscount = ticketPrice * agesSize;
    int min;
    min = ages[0];
    for(int i=0;i< agesSize; i++){
        if(ages[i] < min ){
            min = ages[i];
        }
    }
    double discount= min * finalPriceWithoutDiscount / 100;
    cout << discount << endl;
    // expected output from values:[min=11, fPWD = 50]
    // 5.5
    // actual output:
    // 5.00000
    
    
    double truePrice = finalPriceWithoutDiscount - discount;
    cout << std::fixed << truePrice;
    
    // my output:
    // 45.00000
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your calculation of `agesSize` is illegal C++, it causes undefined behaviour. Use `sizeof agesSize / sizeof agesSize[0]` instead.

Comment: The easy answer is that the expression `min * finalPriceWithoutDiscount / 100` is exclusively integer math, so any decimal part of the result will be truncated. The better answer is that when dealing with money, you should be using integers anyway to represent the smallest denomination. Floating point money is literally the plot of Superman 2.

Comment: Not a direct cause of problem:   There is nothing wrong using c-style code.  However, you have marked this post as c++.  And then used c-style array and c-style-element-count computation for your int agesSize;.  C++ has std::array, and it's element count is std::array.size() (returning size_t).  I prefer and strongly recommend "std::vector<int> ages;"  The element count of vector is provided by "size_t agesSize = ages.size();"  Alternately, visit all elements of std::vector<int> ages, in sequence, using std::for_each(...) function. There are lots of convenient methods in the std library.

Answer (score 4):

In your calculation of `discount`, all operands (`min`, `finalPriceWithoutDiscount` and `100`) are of type `int`. The operations performed are therefore *integer operations*. No decimals are produced.

The (integral) *result* of the calculation is then assigned to a floating point variable, and thus converted to floating point. But that happens *after* the computation has been performed in the integer domain.

To fix this problem, cast at least one of your operands to `double`. Or rather, since you’re using a literal (`100`), use a floating point literal:

```
double discount = min * finalPriceWithoutDiscount / 100.0;
```

This causes the operation involving `100.0` (that is, the division) to be performed on floating point numbers instead of integers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and correct answer, that's some weird behaviour compared to other languages, I code in.

Comment: @Olle2411s It’s actually a very widespread (almost ubiquitous) behaviour of statically-typed languages, and even beyond that: even some non-statically typed languages (e.g. Python 2) have the exact same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer actually answers your question, but I thought I'd contribute a more C++ example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> ages{11, 18, 19, 30, 34};
  int ticketPrice = 10;
  /*for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      cin >> ages[i];
  }*/
  int finalPriceWithoutDiscount = ticketPrice * ages.size();
  int min = *std::min_element(ages.begin(), ages.end());

  // Fix the calculation by using a double, 100.0
  double discount = min * finalPriceWithoutDiscount / 100.0;
  std::cout << discount << '\n';

  // Fix by casting to double
  double truePrice = static_cast<double>(finalPriceWithoutDiscount) - discount;
  std::cout << std::fixed << truePrice;

  return 0;
}
```